# Is IE9 full compatible with extJS2.2

Tags: javascript, extjs, javascript-framework, internet-explorer-9

Does anybody know, is extjs2.2 compatible with IE9?

Comment: or rather, Is extJS2.2 fully compatible with IE9? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ext 2.2 is *not* fully compatible with IE9 as it uses some pretty terrible user agent sniffing to adapt.

You can take a look at one of my [bug reports in the forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?99636-Ext-JS-and-browser-sniffing&p=469222&viewfull=1#post469222) that explains the issue.

Depending on the features you need to use you might not notice this, but if doing drag'n'drop and other stuff depending on certain mouse behavior then things will break.

Hopefully Sencha will take to their senses sometime soon about feature detection, because except for this it's a pretty time saving product..

Comment: They've overhauled the feature detection in ExtJS 4. It's probably worth noting that even ExtJS 3.3.1 (their latest stable release) isn't compatible with IE9 but they will be releasing a compatibility patch for ExtJS 3 as soon as IE9 is released.

Comment: To be fair, Ext 2.2 was released well before IE9 was ever even an alpha browser. But yes, feature detection is quite better in 4.x.

Comment: @bmoeskau, really not a valid argument as had they used Feature Detection back then even Ext2.2 would work in IE9. Now they are actually cripling all old sites, forcing owners to spend time and money on upgrading something that 'worked'.

Comment: Not really an "argument" just a comment. There was a time when no one did feature detection, and it's just taken Ext longer than some others to adapt.  There's no evil plot.

Comment: Thank you guys for quick and good response. For now we forced our project to render in IE8 document mode.

Comment: Given the issues with 3.x that I'm having in a Magento installation, umm, ptch! NO!